# Changing html title value dynamically with Thymeleaf and Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My webpage is rendering each page (~20 pages) with a general wrapper and including it via Thymeleaf `(th:include="wrapper :: page")`. Im adding ViewControllers for those pages as follows: "`registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");`" (example)

Now my question.. since i want to change the title html tag dynamically for each page..
(    `<meta name="title" th:content="${title}"/>`)... 
is it OK if i change my current addViewController methods for a new Controller, @RequestMapping  each page and adding a model `model.addAttribute("title", titleVariable);`?

 Or it would be seen as bad practice to add so many @RequestMapping methods for just changing the html title attribute? is there otherwise another better way of changing the title tag dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the page-layout head:

```
<title layout:title-pattern="$LAYOUT_TITLE - $CONTENT_TITLE">Site name</title>
```

and it will pull in all titles on your included pages when you have the template setup like this:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" layout:decorate="~{direcory/pagename}">
<head>
    <title>This title will appear</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use jQuery?

```
$('title').text($('meta[name="title"]')[0].content);
```

or store it in a variable first

```
var title = $('meta[name="title"]')[0].content;
$('title').text(title);
```